# How to combine an event with a function in jquery

Tags: jquery, function, events

I can't find the solution, I have this function:

```
function handle(varName) {
      if (varName < 0)
          window.location="#div1";
      else 
          window.location="#div2";
};
```

and I want to combine it with an event like

```
(#container1).mouseover
```

And I want to change `window.location` links according the container where my mouse is.

For example:

```
    (#container1).mouseover + varName < 0 = window.location="#div1"
    (#container1).mouseover + else = window.location="#div2"
    (#container2).mouseover + varName < 0 = window.location="#div3"
    (#container2).mouseover + else= window.location="#div4"
```

Comment: Hi, the way your question is written is very confusing. It is not clear what you want your code to do.

Comment: The function allows to know if there are some mouse wheel movements, in one hand (if) there is upward movements in other (else) there is downward movements.
I have 3 container which has each one a anchor (div1,div2,div3).I want my code allows to go to the anchor above or to the anchor below when I am on a specific container. ex:if I'm on container2 I could go only to div1 or div3.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#container1').mouseover(function() {
    handle(varName);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply bind that using function name:

```
('#container1').mouseover(handle);
```

but mouseover event will not pass varName parameter to function.
You should think other approach to get varName